# Get first day of current month in php

Tags: php

I am looking for a similar PHP date function. I need the current month's first day. This month is September. the September month's first day is Wednesday. I need this one like this. Advance Thanks

Comment: _I need_ is not a question. Please show us your best attempt (code). What research have you done? Where are you stuck? Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$thisMonthsFirstDay = (new DateTime('first day of this month'))->format('l');
```

Also always take a look into the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), you can learn a lot from there.